Why @nx/esbuild desn't include functions from the lodash-es into the bundle?
UPD:
OK, my bad, it looks like this is not the esbuild's problem, but NX Build system. The same configuration made for the clean esbuild works just fine, everything is included in the bundle, but if I use the NX plugin "@nx/esbuild" I have the mentioned problem. I'll update the title and tags.
The question is still valid: what hidden configuration of the @nx/esbuild makes it impossible to include the lodash-es functions from being bundled?
Original Post
I'm creating a plugin for the Chrome browser and using esbuild to create a single js file from the set of the typescript files, everything is fine except that esbuild does not include the function from the lodash-es, it the typescript file I have an import:
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es';

and the very same import I see in the resulting plugin.js. All other typescript files are compiled and bundled just well.
My esbuild configuration is quite simple:
{
  sourcemap: true,
  keepNames: true,
  minify: false,
  bundle: true,
  plugins: [lessLoader()]
}

